# Django filter by annotated field is too slow

Tags: django, annotate, django-rest-framework

I use DRF and I have model Motocycle, which has > 2000 objects in DB. Model has one brand. I want to search by full_name:

```
queryset = Motocycle.objects.prefetch_related(
        "brand"
        ).annotate(
            full_name=Concat(
                'brand__title',
                Value(' - '),
                'title',
            )
        )
    )
```

I want to filter by full_name, but query is running very slowly:

```
(1.156) SELECT "mp_api_motocycle"."id"...
```

Without filtering with pagination:

```
(3.980) SELECT "mp_api_motocycle"."id"...
```

There is some possibilty to make this query faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep your full_name annotation as a column in the database and add an index to it.

Otherwise, you are doing full table scan while calculating full_name and then sorting by it.

Comment: `full_name` will be a DB column, and models attribute, which will be updated before model is saved? Or I understanded you wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Yes it will be model field, which will be updated on save, it can be said that this is bit denormalization to benefit performance

Comment: Also, why are you using prefetch_related if there is only one brand, better to use select_related